# error installing zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework2

Hy, I've got this problem, how do I solve it?

'C:\websites\test>php composer.phar install' 'Loading composer repositories with package information' 'Installing dependencies (including require-dev)' ' - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.2.5)' 'Failed to download zendframework/zendframework from dist: You must enable the op' 'enssl extension to download files via https' 'Now trying to download from source' ' - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.2.5)' ' Cloning 4a7cf6a4cf791244e14aa0ca49d1f06916b63202'

'[RuntimeException]' 'Failed to clone git@github.com:zendframework/zf2.git, git was not found, ch' 'eck that it is installed and in your PATH env.'

''git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,' ' operable program or batch file.'

'install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-p' 'lugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--ver' 'bose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]'

thanks!!!

Comment: You have to install Git

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems

**Problem 1**

you got an error while downloading zf2 from the zf repository because they only support ssl connections. The reason you got that error is that your php cli php.ini file doesn't have the openssl extension enabled. You have to find where your php installation stores the php.ini file for php cli and uncomment the line

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

by removing the ; in front of it

**Problem 2**

When you notify composer to download the latest source code. Composer gets this code from Github. Composer uses git to download this code from Github to your computer. You either don't have git installed or you don't have the git executable in your PATH location.

Comment: great, it worked for me. I also had to set extension_dir="C:\Path-to\PHP\ext"